# Analog to Ramanujan Master theorem and questions regarding operational methods

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

A well-known and very useful result by Ramanujan is his Master theorem regarding integrals of the type $$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,x^{s-1}f(x)=\Gamma(s)\phi(-s)$$
where $\phi(s)$ is the coefficient in the power series of $f$: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\phi(n)}{n!}(-x)^n.$$
He derived it formally by introducing the shift operator $\hat{\lambda}^m\phi(n)=\phi(n+m)$ and rewriting the series definition as follows:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\hat{\lambda}^n\phi(0)}{n!}(-x)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-\hat{\lambda} x)^n}{n!}\phi(0)=e^{-\hat{\lambda} x}\phi(0).$$
Now we can perform the integration (treating $\lambda$ as just a number/parameter) and recover the result. Similary to this, he also derived the relation
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,\sin(qx)f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\phi(-2n-2)q^{2n+1}=\phi(-2)q-\phi(-4)q^3+\dotsi$$
by the same means:
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,\sin(qx)f(x)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\,\sin(qx)e^{-\hat{\lambda} x}\phi(0)=\frac{q}{q^2+\hat{\lambda}^2}\phi(0).$$
Now remains the question how to interpret the operator $\frac{q}{q^2+\hat{\lambda}^2}\phi(0)$? For this Ramanujan formally expands the fraction and writes:
$$\frac{q}{q^2+\hat{\lambda}^2}\phi(0)=\frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}^2}\frac{q}{1+\left(\frac{q}{\hat{\lambda}}\right)^2}\phi(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nq^{2n+1}\hat{\lambda}^{-2n-2}\phi(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\phi(-2n-2)q^{2n+1}$$
Is this the only correct way to treat the operator? So could we have expanded the fraction like
$$\frac{q}{q^2+\hat{\lambda}^2}\phi(0)=\frac{1}{q}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{\hat{\lambda}}{q}\right)^2}\phi(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nq^{-2n-1}\hat{\lambda}^{2n}\phi(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\phi(2n)}{q^{2n+1}}$$
and still get meaningful results, maybe interpreting the sum as asymptotic series? I tried it for some functions and got (seemingly) correct asymptotic series.

Then I read in a paper about integral equations of the form
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\xi\,u(x-\xi^2)=f(x)$$
that can be solved again using the (continuous) shift operator $e^{-\xi^2\hat{D}}u(x)=u(x-\xi^2)$ and writing
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\xi\,u(x-\xi^2)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\xi\,e^{-\xi^2\hat{D}}u(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\hat{D}}}u(x)=f(x)$$
from which we now can derive the equation
$$u(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\hat{D}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)$$
where $\hat{D}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the $\frac{1}{2}$-th fractional derivative. What does the breakown of this method for integral equations of the type
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}\xi\,u(x\color{red}{\boldsymbol{+}}\xi^2)=f(x)$$
tell us? Are there no solutions or is this merely a limitation of this approach (maybe because there are convergence or commutativity issues)? (The paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.0184.pdf)

I know that these operational methods are often a bit handwavy but offer nontheless a simple method for solving a bunch of integrals.

Comment: Would $\kappa1=1$ or $2$?